# Accessing Auth in Exceptions\Handler.php

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I'm trying to access the `Auth` class from within the render method of the `App\Exceptions\Handler` class (app/Exceptions/Handler.php) to determine if the User is currently logged in, using the `Auth::check()` method.

This worked fine in 5.1, but I've upgraded to 5.2 and it no longer works.

To debug this, I've been printing `Auth::user()` to the logs (which returns NULL), then returning a redirect() to another view.

Then from the view/controller the redirect goes to, printing the same `Auth::user()` to the logs, which works as expected and returns the logged in user.

So it seems there's no problem accessing the Auth class or the user() method from within the `Exceptions\Handler` class, it's just that it returns NULL for some reason, whereas other parts of the app return the User..

Thanks for any info on this!

Comment: Is your exception being throw before the user/session is authenticated? If so that would explain why you cannot access the value.

Answer (score 13):

This happens because `StartSession` middleware is inside `$middlewareGroups` (*the application's route middleware groups*), so you don't have access to the authenticated user because the middlewares that initialize your session starts later in the lifecycle than the `ExceptionHandler`.

In `app\Kernel.php` file, move this line:

```
 \Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class,
```

from `$middlewareGroups` to the global stack `$middleware`. These middleware are run during every request to your application so, after this, `Auth::user()` will works.

---

> **WARNING:** With this solution you will not be able to use the **`cookie` session driver**. Works well with **`file`** and others.

---

**UPDATE:**

If you still need to use `StartSession` inside global stack `$middleware` and also you need `cookie session driver`, you must move three middlewares from `$middlewareGroup` to `$middleware` in the next order:

```
\App\Http\Middleware\EncryptCookies::class,
\Illuminate\Cookie\Middleware\AddQueuedCookiesToResponse::class,
\Illuminate\Session\Middleware\StartSession::class
```

Answer (score 3):

After some research, it seems the 404 errors are the only culprits. If it's a 500 error, Auth::user() works. So, in my routes.php file, I added this at the bottom

```
Route::any('{page}', 'ErrorController@Error404')->where('page', '(.*)');
```

to catch any unhandled endpoints. In that ErrorController@Error404 method, I can access the Auth class. So whatever logic you have in your `App\Exceptions\Handler`, you can duplicate it in the `ErrorController@Error404` method. (Or better: extract it to some other entity that can be referenced in both places.)